# В position: sticky; не захватываются ссылки

Tags: html, css, position

На первый взгляд всё работает нормально, опускается, поднимается и т.д., но при опускании, ссылки которые были в блоке перестали работать. Компьютер их просто не видит, для него они остались на том месте где они были при открытии.

```
#anchors{
position:-webkit-sticky;
position: sticky;
top: 10%;
left: 80%;
margin-right: 2em;
margin-top: 30em;
padding: 1%;
width: 20%;
border: 2px white solid;
border-radius: 5px;
background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/wLmzFGq/paper.png);
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 1.8;
.anchor{
color: red;}
```

У меня отдельный CSS файл.

Comment: Составьте [mcve] вместе с html-разметкой

Comment: `z-index` пробовали прописать плавающему элементу?

Comment: Да пробовал, хотя возможно не правильно. Я только учусь этому всему и не очень разбираюсь. Если сможете скиньте пример.